# Date format issue

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date-time, windows-10-v1703, excel-filter

I export some files from a network as CSV and then I convert that file as excel file there is one column in excel file named-as (dates) now when I apply the filter on it the filter is not slowing correct info due to two different formats in dates. one of them is correct but the other one is not I want to make them same format but they are not customizing according to my need

[image: sample code]

in this image, the above two dates are according to my need and the rest which are aligned left is not in the format that I want

please help me to have them in the same format

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! We are not a free coding service but a community of people interested in computers that are willing to share their knowledge and experience. If you have already tried something please post it here, otherwise this question is likely to be closed due to lack of preliminary work from your side.

Comment: How did you eport the .csv file to Excel? Did set the Date format for the column?

Comment: you should add a sample of the csv file, not just the result after importing; it looks as if the top cells use mm-dd-yy format, but the csv input is dd-mm-yy?

Comment: Do not **OPEN** the csv file. Rather you should **IMPORT** the file using either the legacy wizard or Power Query. If you do that, you will be able to tell Excel the format of the date column, before it misinterprets things.

Answer (score 1):

##### String vs. Number

Excel is interpreting some of your *dates* as text strings and some as numbers.  The source data holds the root of the problem, and fixing that prior to export will eliminate your issue.  If however you want to clean up the mix of formats after the fact,  you can convert the text strings to proper dates using a formula.

##### Assumptions

*These assumptions are for the dates stored as strings.  Your actual dates will follow whatever format is applied to the cells.*

- the **day**, **month** and **year** are delimited with a slash <kbd>/</kbd>
- the **month** and the **day** precede the **year** `mm/dd/yy` or `dd/mm/yy`
- **month** and **day** can be one or two characters `2/8` or `02/8` or `2/08` etc.
- the **year** can be 2 or 4 characters `12/21/2022` or `12/21/22`

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Displayed** | **Actual Value** | **Converted** | **Formatted** |
| 2 | 12/27/2020 | 44192 | 44192 | 12/27/20 0:00 |
| 3 | 12/20/2020 | 44185 | 44185 | 12/20/20 0:00 |
| 4 | 19/12/20 04:23:48 | 19/12/20 04:23:48 | 44184.18319 | 12/19/20 4:23 |
| 5 | 13/09/20 03:46:16 | 13/09/20 03:46:16 | 44087.15713 | 09/13/20 3:46 |
| 6 | 13/09/20 | 13/09/20 | 44087 | 09/13/20 0:00 |
| 7 | 13/9/20 05:51:10 | 13/9/20 05:51:10 | 44087.24387 | 09/13/20 5:51 |
| 8 | 13/9/2020 06:19:27 | 13/9/2020 06:19:27 | 44087.26351 | 09/13/20 6:19 |

##### Conversion Formula

Uses a minimal test to accept the displayed `date` value if it is a number, or else re-arrange its day and month.  It doesn't know or care what the original and new order actually is, only that it will flip them.

In cell $C$2 in sample table above:

```
=BYROW(A2:A8, LAMBDA(x, IFERROR(x*1,
      TEXTJOIN("/",, INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(x,"/"),1,2),
                     INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(x,"/"),1,1),
                     INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(x,"/"),1,3))*1)))
```

Column C and column D in the sample table above have the same values.  Column C is formatted as a decimal number and column D is formatted with an arbitrary Date/Time format.