# Exported Excel can't be formatted

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have Excel files from all sorts of sources.

For example, a Excel report from PayPal.

Now, I want to sort the cells by date. It won't work because Excel doesn't recognize the dates as dates.

- `CMD + 1` and then formatting the cells has no effect.
- When I import a CSV, I can change the format in the Power Query UI. But this only shows up with CSV. Many services, however, only export Excel.

So how do I change the format of an external Excel? Is there a possibility to open a .xls file in the Power Query? I can't find anything.

Example file from PayPal: https://we.tl/t-ZoqToKIZk1

I have the latest Excel on a Mac.

Comment: If you highlight 2 or more cells does it start totaling in the bottom corner. It sounds like the values maybe treated as text. Assuming this is the case,  Click on the column header to highlight everything. then in Data>Text to Columns. Outside of that paste an picture of your issue as your link doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Your example spreadsheet has no data.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1757808/1007040) help with the date format issue?

Comment: @BradR Link was working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove merged cell in the top (press merge and center)

Select column A

Data-->Text to columns

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

or
Format column A as Short Date and select a cell
press F2 (or double click) and enter

or
Format any cell to General and write 1.
Copy cell, select cells in column A and paste special multiply.
After that format as Short date

[image]

[image]

or like this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kqmv06Xbj3A

Comment: Awesome. Thank you